# Snowflake Window function

Tags: window, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Did anything change in the window function. I see a query that ran yesterday looked as below

[image]

Today it looks as below

[image]

Comment: Can you include the entire profile of each query?  A lot of things go into the profile of a query that could affect things between runs that don't relate to Snowflake version changes.  For example, one query could be benefiting from cache where one may not be.  Also, were the tables updated between runs?  Perhaps the characteristics of the data changed the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know this is because of a corruption in the query profile. have reported this issue and this is being worked upon

Answer (score 1):

If you grab some QUERY_IDs for that query on recent runs, you can see the Snowflake version when they ran. You can run that for some recent ones to see if the version changed around the time you saw the change in behavior:

```
select RELEASE_VERSION from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" 
where QUERY_ID = '01920978-00b4-2a98-0000-00009d1d81f5';
```

Edit: I decided that it might be helpful to anyone reading this to have a general-purpose query to see their Snowflake version history:

```
select      to_date(min(START_TIME))  as START_DATE,
            to_date(max(START_TIME))  as END_DATE,
            RELEASE_VERSION           as SNOWFLAKE_VERSION
from        "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
group by    RELEASE_VERSION
order by    START_DATE desc;
```